# Android - How to fix GIF size

Tags: java, android, size, gif

### I coding App to show GIF Image and it can show on any device but on Asus Memo Pad HD 7(ME173X) can't show and I look in Log it show this

08-20 13:16:08.612: D/skia(6281): SkGIFMovie:SkGIFMovie: GIF 0,Cidx -1,LDidx -1

08-20 13:16:08.630: D/skia(6281): SkGIFMovie:checkGifStream: total pixels(12320000) is larger than 10485760!!

08-20 13:16:08.671: D/libEGL(6281): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so

08-20 13:16:08.686: D/libEGL(6281): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so

08-20 13:16:08.691: D/libEGL(6281): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so

08-20 13:16:08.739: D/OpenGLRenderer(6281): Enabling debug mode 0

08-20 13:16:08.742: D/skia(6281): Flag is not 10

08-20 13:16:08.744: D/skia(6281): Flag is not 10

08-20 13:16:08.780: V/InputMethodManager(6281): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100

08-20 13:16:08.782: V/InputMethodManager(6281): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41517f88 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-800,1216} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4154bd28 controlFlags=#104

08-20 13:16:08.783: V/InputMethodManager(6281): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{null com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME #1587}

08-20 13:16:08.785: D/dalvikvm(6281): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x557bf000

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is not really related to the GIF. I had the same problem todan on an Asus tablet, switching the tablet's language language from english to Spanish solved it. Do the same or try to change it to a latin language (with accents) or another one that you prefer.
It is strange, but works.